# how to input data from multiple columns in x and y arguments in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a density plot for particle size data. My data has multiple density and size readings for each genotype set. Is there a way to specify multiple columns into x and y using ggplot? I tried coding for this but am only getting a blank plot as of now. This is the link to the csv file I used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11djXTmZliPCGLCZavukjb0TT28HsKMRQ/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

```
crop.data6 <- read.csv("barleygt25.csv", header = TRUE)
crop.data6

library(ggplot2)

plot1 = ggplot(data=crop.data6, aes(x=, xend=bq, y=a, yend=bq, color=genotype))
plot1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in a strange format that doesn't lend itself well to plotting. Effectively, it needs to be transposed then pivoted into long format to make it suitable for plotting:

```r
df <- data.frame(xvals    = c(t(crop.data6[1:9, -c(1:2)])),
                 yvals    = c(t(crop.data6[10:18, -c(1:2)])),
                 genotype = rep(crop.data6$genotype[1:9], each = 68))

ggplot(df, aes(xvals, yvals, color = genotype)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = "value", y = "density")
```

[image]